# I need to do a view in sql that returns the latest invoice date for each company

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a company table that is `dbo.companies` and has `companyId` as a column. I also have an invoice table that is `dbo.invoices` with `invoicecompanyId` column (which is the same as the `companyId` on the other table) and it also has a column called `invoicedate`.
What I am trying to achieve is a view of each `companyid` with the corresponding latest invoice date for all the companies I have.

I have done the following but I don't know how to filter for the latest invoice, it returns all invoices from all companies and I need latest invoice for all companies

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT 
    'A' + 
    SUBSTRING('000000', 1, 6 - LEN(CAST(dbo.companies.companyId AS varchar(10)))) +
    CAST(dbo.companies.companyId AS varchar(10)) AS Client_ID, 
    dbo.invoices.invoiceDate AS S_Inv_Date
FROM dbo.invoices 
INNER JOIN dbo.companies 
ON dbo.invoices.invoiceCompanyId = dbo.companies.companyId
ORDER BY Client_ID
```

Can you help please?

ta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
       SUBSTRING('000000', 1, 6 - LEN(CAST(dbo.companies.companyId AS varchar(10)))) +
           CAST(dbo.companies.companyId AS varchar(10)) AS Client_ID
     , b.mxDate maxInvoiceDate
  FROM dbo.companies c
     , (SELECT dbo.invoices.invoiceCompanyId companyId
             , MAX(dbo.invoices.invoiceDate) mxDate
          FROM dbo.invoices
        GROUP BY dbo.invoices.invoiceCompanyId ) b
 WHERE c.companyId = b.companyId
 ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: eww, you converted ANSI-92 to ANSI-89 join syntax?!  And used an ordinal in the order by...

Comment: Hey, it worked didn't it :).  I prefer the join syntax used above, it's less wordy and it makes the WHERE clause much nicer looking if you are joining many tables IMHO. Nothing wrong with old-school, right? :).

Answer (score 0):

Can you `order by S_Inv_Date descending` to get the needed results?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a GROUP BY and a MAX.  Quick & dirty sample:

```
SELECT cy.companyId, cy.CompanyName, max(inv.invoiceDate) as LastInv 
FROM companies as cy, invoices as inv
GROUP BY cy.companyId, cy.CompanyName
WHERE cy.companyId = inv.companyId
```